# sql how i select actors who also producers

Tags: mysql, sql

everyone.
I am new in sql and just wonder how to select all id_peoples from table who have both professions with one select.

my table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE `films_peoples_prof` (
  `id_film` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_people` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_profession` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_film`,`id_people`,`id_profession`),
  KEY `id_people` (`id_people`),
  KEY `id_profession` (`id_profession`),
  CONSTRAINT `films_peoples_prof_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_film`) REFERENCES `films` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `films_peoples_prof_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_people`) REFERENCES `peoples` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `films_peoples_prof_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_profession`) REFERENCES `professions` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)


+---------+-----------+---------------+
| id_film | id_people | id_profession |
+---------+-----------+---------------+
|       4 |         1 |             1 |
|       4 |         1 |             2 |
|       5 |         1 |             1 |
|       7 |         1 |             1 |
|       4 |         2 |             1 |
|       4 |         3 |             1 |
|       5 |         3 |             1 |
|       6 |         3 |             1 |
|       4 |         4 |             1 |
|       8 |         5 |             1 |
|       9 |         5 |             1 |
|       4 |         6 |             1 |
|       4 |         6 |             2 |
|       9 |         7 |             2 |
|       4 |        10 |             1 |
+---------+-----------+---------------+
```

id = 1 -actor, id = 2 - producer
in this case result should be 1 , 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `group by` like

```
select id_people 
from films_peoples_prof
where id_profession in (1,2)
group by id_people 
having count(distinct id_profession ) = 2;
```

Comment: result is 1, 3, 5, 6 But should be 1, 6

Comment: Well, it's never going to be greater than 2, is it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id_people
FROM films_peoples_prof
WHERE id_proffesion = 1
    AND id_people IN (
        SELECT id_people
        FROM films_peoples_prof
        WHERE id_profession = 2
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id_film
  ,id_people
  ,COUNT(id_profession) as CTR
FROM films_peoples_prof
GROUP BY film, people
HAVING CTR > 1
```

Comment: this doesnt working if people is actor in one film and producer in a different one, sorry for english

Comment: just remove "id_film" from the select and group by clause

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
select people.id_people 
from films_peoples_prof people, films_peoples_prof prof
where people.id_people = prof.id_profession
group by people.id_people 
having count(distinct prof.id_profession ) = 1;
```

I have been used self join concept.This query work for me.